# React Native: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require (line 1 in the generated bundle)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I created a sample app in react native using following guide

[React native android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#content)

But when i Run `react-native run-android`. I am getting following exception.

```
 11-25 16:10:35.326 1796-1897/com.awesome E/ReactNative: Got JS Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
11-25 16:10:35.327 1796-1897/com.awesome E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_js
                                                           Process: com.awesome, PID: 1796


com.facebook.react.bridge.JSExecutionException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require (line 1 in the generated bundle)
                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.loadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:32)
                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstance$2.run(CatalystInstance.java:138)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThread$1.run(MessageQueueThread.java:137)
                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Anybody please help me how to resolve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254641/android-library-project-with-react-native
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3379

Comment: Some problem. None from the answears solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 18):

I've had the same problem, following steps from the documentation and trying to run the generated sample app, without any change.

Turned out there was something not mentioned in docs: you have to launch a server (I thought this was what the build was doing at last steps, but it was not enough).

To do so, launch in your project root folder:

```
react-native start
```

Comment: awesome, it was a reason, finally I run "hello world" example!

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and the fix was starting adb.
Did you run adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if you have react.gradle file in your gradle files. Try bundling the asset manually if you do not have this file.

Reference: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content

Answer (score 0):

make sure your phone and machine are in the same network